# SQL query optimization for past order history check

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

Part a particular process with order processing involves checking if it is the user's first order.

This is very slow and causing issues with the process performance.

```
SELECT IF (COUNT(*) > 0, FALSE, TRUE) AS is_first_order
FROM Orders o 
LEFT JOIN OrderCancellations oc
ON o.id = oc.orderID
WHERE o.customerId = xxxx
AND oc.orderID IS NULL
LIMIT 1;
```

The EXPLAIN shows it scans the orders table which is around 2mil records.

Comment: Asking about optimization you must provide complete CREATE TABLE for all used tables.

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is a lottery...

Comment: `COUNT(*)` cannot be less than 1.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: You need an index on table Orders that contains at least the columns id and customerId because both are accessed in that query. id for joining the other table and customerId because you filter by that

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with `SELECT IF (COUNT(*) > 0, FALSE, TRUE) ... LIMIT 1`:

- The last arg is the false option; it is very confusing to say `TRUE`.
- A boolean expression deliver `FALSE` or `TRUE`, so there is no need to have the `IF(...)`.
- There is only an aggregate, so there will be only one rows.  That is, the `LIMIT` has no effect.  Probably you need to have a subquery doing `( SELECT COUNT(*) ... )`
- `FALSE` is `0`; if you want the string `FALSE`, then use `"FALSE"`.